# I am trying to make a page in the admin section similar to the appearance of the Profile page for users

Tags: plugin-development, admin-menu, input

I am working on a plugin and would like to know the correct way I go about creating a page that will look like the users page (image attached at the buttom)

The fields will be different and will add data(the data is unrelated to user information) to a new table created by the plugin . So it does not seem like the Settings API will help me.

I am strictly talking about appearance. Should I just use the css built in wordpress or is there some sort of function that will help me create all the fields?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to create a page for your plugin which mimics the look and feel of the WordPress Dashboard and it's option pages?

If so then you can use the CSS which is packed with WordPress. The CSS file is located at wp-admin/wp-admin.css

If you open that file with your code editor you can inspect some of the styling. Using this in conjunction with a code inspector like Firebug or Google Inspector you can check items you want to mimic by "inspecting" them and simply name your elements with the same style or ID that you wish to mimic for your plugin

Craig